# How can I make a no-op event in C# WinRT?

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml

In .NET, if I'm implementing an interface that contains an event, but that event makes no sense for my object (say it's a change event and I'm writing an immutable object), then I can just provide empty bodies for `add` and `remove` -- a null implementation. This avoids allocating storage for a delegate field I'll never use, and also avoids the "event is never used" compiler warning, so it's a win all around.

```
public event EventHandler Changed {
    add {}
    remove {}
}
```

When I try the same thing in a WinRT class (descends from FrameworkElement), I get a compiler error on the `add` accessor: "not all code paths return a value".

How do I return a value from an `add` accessor? What's it supposed to return?

**Update:** Apparently this problem only applies to WinRT events (e.g., if you're implementing a WinRT interface that contains an event). If you're writing a plain old CLR event, the above syntax works.

Comment: I created a Metro class library and had one class inherit from `Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement`. I added your `event` code from above, and this builds without problems? (VS 2011 Beta)

Comment: I got the error in VS 2012 RC. Maybe they changed it since the beta?

Comment: That's not a win, that's a "why the heck doesn't my event handler run?" exclamation somewhere down the road.  Throw a NotImplementedException instead.  Other than that, events are very different on WinRT.  They are cookie based, COM IConnectionPoint style, you have to store it in an EventRegistrationTokenTable.

Comment: @HansPassant, that's silly. It's an *immutable object.* If you can't figure out why your *immutable object* is never firing the *Changed event,* then you've got other problems. And I want to be able to pass this object to code that doesn't *know* whether it's getting an immutable object or not, so throwing NotImplementedException is absolutely the wrong thing to do. That code should be able to say "Tell me when you change", and I should be able to say "okay". The fact that I'll never change isn't something my consumers should need to care about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So based on the link Anders [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11099920/87399), it looks like the `add` accessor needs to return an [`EventRegistrationToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.windowsruntime.eventregistrationtoken(v=vs.110).aspx). `EventRegistrationToken` is just a struct, apparently with no fields, and no constructors beyond the default, so it looks like I could harmlessly `new` one up -- especially since the only code that will consume it is my `remove`, which doesn't care.

So the WinRT equivalent of the null event appears to be:

```
public event EventHandler Changed {
    add { return new EventRegistrationToken(); }
    remove {}
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh972883%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) article on the Windows Dev Center. It seems like the `add` and `remove` accessor functionality has indeed changed with Metro:

> .NET Framework support for the Windows Runtime makes it easy to declare events in Windows Runtime Components by hiding the differences between the Windows Runtime event pattern and the .NET Framework event pattern. However, when you declare custom event accessors in a Windows Runtime component, you must follow the Windows Runtime pattern.
>
> When you register to handle an event in the Windows Runtime, the add accessor returns a token. To unregister, you pass this token to the remove accessor. This means that the add and remove accessors for Windows Runtime events have different signatures from the accessors you're used to.
>
> Fortunately, the Visual Basic and C# compilers simplify this process: When you declare an event with custom accessors in a Windows Runtime component, the compilers automatically use the Windows Runtime pattern. For example, you get a compiler error if your add accessor doesn't return a token.
>
> The .NET Framework provides two types to support the implementation:
>
> - The EventRegistrationToken structure represents the token.
> - The EventRegistrationTokenTable<T> class creates tokens and maintains a mapping between tokens and event handlers. The generic type argument is the event argument type. You create an instance of this class for each event, the first time an event handler is registered for that event.